# String .equals opposite

Tags: java

I have this line of code:

```
if(command.equals("e") || command.equals("d")) {
   //statements
}
```

Comment: The opposite of `"this".equals("that")` is `!"this".equals("that")`.

Comment: You can always use `!command.equals("e")`, assuming that this was your question, of course.

Comment: not (A or B) == not A and not B

Comment: You should explain you're needs or further explain the question. I don't know if you are asking for a method that does the opposite of equals or if you want the opposite of the statement.

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of

`(command.equals("e") || command.equals("d"))`

is

`(!(command.equals("e") || command.equals("d")))`

or in a different form

`(!command.equals("e") && !command.equals("d"))`

Comment: Yes, it's DeMorgan's Theorem.